# Simple Snippet to read and show content from file

Tags: php

I am looking for a simple solution to add a Snippet in my index.php file to load and display the content shown in a file from an other Domain.

Plan was to add the Code to the 'Footer' before  to show a floating ad on several of my websites.

Sourcesite: http://domainX.tld/floating/floater.txt
Content of file: little bit css for styling of the ad + script snippet for a close button + html to get it into shape.

Target Site gets a simple snippet to show content from txt file as its own content.

I have tried by now

```
<?php 
    $StrLessDescription = ("//domainX.tld/floating/floater.txt");
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($StrLessDescription);
?>
```

Site loads but doen't shows anything of my code.

```
<?php 
    $handle = fopen("//domainX.tld/floating/floater.txt", "rb");
    $delimiter = ",";
    while (!feof($handle) ) {
        $line = fgets($handle);
        $data = explode($delimiter, $line);
        foreach($data as $v) {
            echo $v;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

Site wouldn't even load.

```
<?php
    $f = fopen("//domain.tld/floating/floatr.txt", "r");
    // Read line by line until end of file
    while(!feof($f)) { 
        echo fgets($f) . "<br />";
    }
    fclose($f);
?>
```

Creates an endless amount of 
 where my Code should be

Other Fails i have deleted already.

Once i had a simple snippet that had done the trick, does one have any idea how to accomplish that again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('//domain.tld/floating/floatr.txt');
```

Comment: Works great... after i add http://www. indtead of just // .. seems I just have tried it directly the right way. Even if my browser understoof to open //domain.tld, the file_get_contents Command didn't. Thank you very much, just have to fix now an issue that it ignores the added css code.. maybe i should add this to all sites in their main css directly, so it can be used without adding it to the txt file.

Comment: I have to correct myself here I think. Just realized that the CSS format that i was missing simply was hidden under the Navigation. The Floater was simply located 20px from top and right... changing it to 60px from top showed the Close Button again. So CSS is working, just my fault that it was not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to the straightest way to do it as your intention is and supposing that:

- URL you provide for the txt file is correct
- you have read access to it
- the file has contents to display
- your PHP version is (PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5, PHP 7) to support
  the [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) function

You are missing in your first approach to [echo](http://php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php) the contents of your variable *$StrLessDescription* to send it to output.

```
<?php

    $StrLessDescription = ("//domainX.tld/floating/floater.txt");
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($StrLessDescription);
    echo $file_contents;

?>
```

Remember that for **large projects** you could consider using a *framework* to achieve the same goal in a more organized way. This is a solution to a quick-and-dirty approach you inquiry.

Comment: I can answer you the same way as I did before: Works great... after i add www. indtead of just // .. seems I just have tried it directly the right way. Even if my browser understoof to open //domain.tld, the file_get_contents Command didn't. Thank you very much, just have to fix now an issue that it ignores the added css code.. maybe i should add this to all sites in their main css directly, so it can be used without adding it to the txt file. Additionally: This is just used for like 25 Domains to exchange an Ad that floats in the top right corner depending if there is a Promo or not